# I'm trying to make images to scroll in a div using javascript to create elements

Tags: javascript, dom

// This is the class for the first div in the chain. I create this div in the html document.

```
.content {
    width: 76%;
    line-height: 160%;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    left: 12%;
    z-index: 0;
}
```

// Then I create a div in the first div element and assign it values to make it scrollable.

```
   let div1 = document.createElement('div');
    div1.style.width = "350px";
    div1.style.height = "auto";
    div1.style.margin = "10px";
    div1.style.position = "relative";
    div1.style.display = "inline-block";
    div1.style.whiteSpace = "no-wrap";
    div1.style.overflow = "auto";
    div1.style.border = "2px solid paleturquoise";
    div1.style.borderRadius = "10px";
    div1.id = "divcontain" + x;
```

// Now I get image paths from a string in a database and append them to the div1 element.

```
    pictures = imagepath[x].split(" ");
    for (let z = 0; z < pictures.length; z++) {
        let img = document.createElement('img');
        img.style.width = "320px";
        img.style.height = "auto";
        img.style.float = "left";
        img.style.marginRight = "5px";
        img.src = pictures[z];
        div1.appendChild(img);
    }
```

This code will work if you create the elements in html. But when I create them using javasctipt, I get them stacked vertically with no scroll bar, instead of horizontally with a scroll bar.